# Polyline and polygon not showing in Google Maps for IE8 or IE7

Tags: google-maps, internet-explorer-8, google-maps-api-3

I am drawing polylines and polygons on Google Maps.  They show up correctly in Internet Explorer 9, but not in IE8 or IE7.  I have come across a few posts that talk about a "hanging comma" problem with arrays that was fixed in IE9, and it might be related to the problem I'm having, but I don't see how I would run into that situation because of how my code works.  I create "google.maps.LatLng" objects and "push" them into an array.  I pass the array as the "path" parameter in creating a "google.maps.Polygon" object.  I don't have any code that builds the array by inserting commas between items in a list.

```
var polygonPoints = new Array();

var point1 = new google.maps.LatLng(myLat1, myLong1); 
polygonPoints.push(point1);
var point2 = new google.maps.LatLng(myLat2, myLong2); 
polygonPoints.push(point2);
var point3 = new google.maps.LatLng(myLat3, myLong3); 
polygonPoints.push(point3);

var myPolygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    path: polygonPoints,
    strokeColor: "#FFFF00",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0, strokeWeight: 2, 
    fillOpacity: 0.0
});
```

How can I get the polygon to show in IE8 and IE7?  (Polylines don't show either, but markers do.)

Answer (score 1):

This took some experimentation, but I figured it out.  The fix was to change the following line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Now it works in IE7 and IE8 as well as most other browsers.  Hopefully this will be helpful to someone else!

Answer (score 0):

---

Now it works in IE7 and IE8 as well as most other browsers. Hopefully this will be helpful to someone else!

---

hi MylesRip ! 
I load google map in iframe, but i can't load polygon.
In case, I not use iframe, it work normaly.
The reason I use iframe because I need to avoid broken map when print

- I used your way but does not work

==
I write EN quite bad.